# Add JsonArray data into ArrayList

Tags: java, json, arraylist

How do I add
[jsonArray](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm)
data into an
[ArrayList](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm)
of type Product.

I wrote a test class with dummy json data. The main class is as
follows:

```
public class convertData {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            List<ProductModel> myList = new ArrayList<>();

            JsonArrayBuilder arrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
            JsonObject jsonObject1, jsonObject2, jsonObject3;


            jsonObject1 = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                    .add("id", 1)
                    .add("name", "Albany")
                    .add( "manufacture", "Albany Superior Low Gi Sliced Brown Seed Bread 700g")
                    .add("price", 15.49)
                    .add("category", "Food")
                    .add ("type", "Breads")
                    .add( "image", "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4A" )
                    .build();

            jsonObject2 = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                    .add("id", 1)
                    .add("name", "Albany")
                    .add( "manufacture", "yuyyjjgyced Brown Seed Bread 700g")
                    .add("price", 15.49)
                    .add("category", "Food")
                    .add ("type", "Breads")
                    .add( "image", "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4A" )
                    .build();

            jsonObject3 = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                    .add("id", 1)
                    .add("name", "Albany")
                    .add( "manufacture", "Albany Superior Low Gi Sliced Brown Seed Bread 700g")
                    .add("price", 15.49)
                    .add("category", "Food")
                    .add ("type", "Milk")
                    .add( "image", "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4A" )
                    .build();


            arrayBuilder.add(jsonObject1);
            arrayBuilder.add(jsonObject2);
            arrayBuilder.add(jsonObject3);

            JSONArray jArray = (JSONArray) arrayBuilder; 

            if (jArray != null) { 

                for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){ 
                    myList.add(jArray.get(i));
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I then created a product model class as follows:

```
class ProductModel {

            private int id;
            private String name;
            private String manufacture;
            private Double price;
            private String category;
            private String type;
            private String image;
            // get and setters
            ...
```

I have searched for similar solution, but there were not helpful in a
way.

The project is written using J2SE platform, and I only added the jar
files for json.

The json data I am building looks something like these:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Albany",
        "manufacture": "Albany Superior Low Gi Sliced Brown Seed Bread 700g",
        "price": 15.49,
        "category": "Food",
        "type": "Breads",
        "image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4..."
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Blue Ribbon",
        "manufacture": "Blue Ribbon Brown Plus Low Gi Bread 700g",
        "price": 13.99,
        "category": "Food",
        "type": "Breads",
        "image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZ."
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Cheese",
        "manufacture": "Galbani Mozzarella Cheese 300g",
        "price": 49.99,
        "category": "Food",
        "type": "Cheese",
        "image": "data:image/octet-stream;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRg..."
    }
]
```

Comment: your question is unclear, is the jsonArray a member of ProductModel class?
would be better if you share the expected output as it would look like in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few chnages needs to be done to make it run:

1. Add a constructor in ProductModel class that will accept JsonObject as argument:

   ```
   public ProductModel(JsonObject json) {
       super();
       this.id = json.getInt("id");
       this.name = json.getString("name");
       this.manufacture = json.getString("manufacture");
       this.price = Double.parseDouble(json.getJsonNumber("price").toString());
       this.category = json.getString("category");
       this.type = json.getString("type");
       this.image = json.getString("image");
   }
   ```
2. use JsonArray instead of JSONArray and pass build array to it:

   ```
   JsonArray jArray = arrayBuilder.build();
   ```
3. call newly created  constructor in add method:

   ```
   if (jArray != null) { 

            for (int i=0;i<jArray.size();i++){ 
                myList.add(new ProductModel((JsonObject) jArray.get(i)));
            }
        }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert each JsonObject individually into a `ProductModel` object by doing something like this:

```
new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonObject.toString(), ProductModel.class);
```

Then you can easily add these objects into `ProductModel` type array.

Comment: What I want to do is to add that the jsonArray all-in-all into arrayList and not jsonObject separately.

Comment: He seems to be using json-simple library. Not Jackson.

Comment: 666DESH666 You can iterate on your jsonArray and convert each entry into a ProductModel object. You can use a simple loop or stream.

Answer (score 0):

To be easier to get help, you should explain what libraries you are using. There is one link you have put there to an example that is using **json-simple** so I will assume you use it as well.

Although simple, this library seems to not be documented and just a very few examples out there. Also not that many futures in it (like the one that you are after: to convert the json into a Java object).

One valid option is to use a better documented library for JSON, like Jackson or GSON.

If you want to continue with this, you can write specific adapter to transform JsonObject to ProductModel. Or a more general adapter using reflection to transform JsonObject to a java bean class.